# Chrome.serial onReceive is slow

Tags: performance, google-chrome

Hello I am using the chrome serial API to receive data at interval of 50-100ms.
Here how I connect with the device:

```
serial.connect("COM180", {bitrate: 115200,ctsFlowControl:true}, onDeviceEvent);
chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(parseDataFromDevice);
```

my parseDataFromDevice sometimes is called at the specified interval of 50-100ms but sometimes it fails and deliver messages each 200ms.

I am using this to convert the data received to String:

```
var ab2str = function(buf)
{
return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
};
```

Any idea why this is happening and its so slow ?